# Can't connect to my wireless network though GNOME

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, wifi, networkmanager

I managed to install Archlinux today. But I have no access to my wifi for some reason.

I get internet access in my terminal with `wifi-menu` but gnome tells me that it can not connect to my wireless network. The password is 100% correct.

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Networkmanager#GNOME) and installed `network-manager-applet`, and I also changed the `rc.conf` file:

```
rc.d start networkmanager
```

I also installed `pacman -S networkmanager`

I restarted `networkmanager`, enabled / disabled it, started it again. I also turned the wireless network in GNOME on and off. But nothing helped.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: I don't know Arch, so I might be off here... First, start a terminal, and run `iwconfig`, check if there is a interface that doesn't say "no wireless extensions", probably `wlan0`. Do a `iwlist wlan0 scan` for it, and check what it says, your home network should show up. As root run `nm-online` (probably by using `sudo(1)`). This should get the network going. Please add the results of the above (edit out name of the network and such that might be sensitive) to your question. That should enable Arch-enthusiasts (archimandrites?) to diagnose your problem.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to identify the hardware the installation is on, especially if it is a laptop.  i.e. my Lenovo S12 fails with network manager, so I use WiCD. Also the drivers for the WiFi device ann be troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Arch Linux does **not** use `sysv` any more. We have been using [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) for quite some time now. This means `rc.conf` is **no longer used**.

   - Did you use the latest image from the [download](http://www.archlinux.org/download/) section of the website?
2. There is a new naming scheme for network devices, they will only use names such as `wlan0` and `eth0` if the hardware cannot provide it's own.

   - To view the names of your devices issue the command `ip l` in a terminal.
3. You should read over the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) and click around the wiki to familiarize yourself with how things are done in Arch Linux. The documentation on there is very well put together and very informative. There is also `#archlinux` on `irc.freenode.net` where we provide live support.
4. If your wireless device is not listed in `ip l` then you will have to download and load the necessary modules/drivers for your hardware.

   - To view the hardware on the pci bus you can issue `lspci`.
   - If you're going to need to download the needed modules for it. Then I would suggest booting into the Live USB again and mounting your root partition to `/mnt` just like you did when you installed. Then you can use `pacstrap /mnt` to install whatever it is you'll need.
   - If you have an ethernet cable and port available to use then simply plug it in and `dhcpcd eth0` (be sure to replace eth0 with whatever interface name your wired network controller has).